# Empty FetchedResultsController in Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm using core data and I have an entity defined called LogRecord. Elsewhere this is populated with objects using:

```
        LogRecord *rec = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LogRecord"
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [rec timestampNow];

        rec.moodType = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:i];
        rec.moodValue = value;

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![rec.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            [DataUtil displayFatalError:error message:@"Failed to save log entry"];
            errors++;
        }
```

I've checked and the underlying sqlite database has records in it after using this code.

However, when I try to query for the data using this:

```
 - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController == nil) {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LogRecord"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]    initWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
        [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                            managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                              sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                       cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
        [sortDescriptors release];
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

It comes up empty as evidenced by `[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]` returning zero.

Any idea how I might debug this? It was working before I tried to break this code out into a different UIViewController....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never mind.... Somehow the call to `[[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]` in viewDidLoad got deleted.